# Ionic content not rendering

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, ionic-framework

I am trying to get a really basic page rendering in Ionic and but can't seem to get anything but a white page to appear.

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="vendor/ionic.min.css">
        <title>IoT Launch</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="vendor/vendor.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bundle.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body ng-app="iot-launch">
        <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>
    </body>
</html>
```

Note that I'm using Browserify to generate a vendor.js and bundle.js from 3rd party and my own JavaScript with an entrypoint at js/apps.js.

js/app.js:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('iot-launch', ['ionic', require('./views/deviceList')])

.config(['$urlRouterProvider', function($urlRouterProvider) {
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
}])

.run(['$rootScope', '$state', '$stateParams', function($rootScope, $state, $stateParams) {
    $rootScope.$state = $state;
    $rootScope.$stateParams = $stateParams;

    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeError', console.log.bind(console));
    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', console.log.bind(console));
    $rootScope.$on('$stateNotFound', console.log.bind(console));
    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', console.log.bind(console));
}]);
```

js/views/deviceList.js:

```
module.exports = angular.module('iot-launch.views.deviceList', [
    'ionic'
])

.config(['$stateProvider', function($stateProvider) {
    console.log('In deviceList config');
    $stateProvider
        .state('iot-launch.deviceList', {
            url: '/',
            template: '<ion-view title="hello"><ion-content>Hello</ion-content></ion-view>'
        });
}])

.name;
```

When I replace `<ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>` with the content of the template, it renders on the page (i.e., Hello appears). The only statement appearing in the console is the statement in the the deviceList config so the $stateProvider code appears to be getting called.

I thought the `$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/')`, having the `iot-launch.deviceList` state with a url of `/`, and using `<ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>` in the main html file would lead to the template in `iot-launch.deviceList` appearing where `<ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>` appears.

Comment: any error in console?

Comment: No errors or other logging statements other than `In deviceList config`

Answer (score 0):

I just noticed that I didn't define an `iot-launch` state which is apparently very necessary for an `iot-launch.deviceList` state to work. Removing `.deviceList` from the state name or defining an `iot-launch` state seems to fix it. The lack of error messages was very aggravating.